# Minecraft Server Security

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

My son has a huge nostalgic side to him and he wants to host an old version of a Minecraft server.  What would be the oldest version of Minecraft server that I can securely run on a Linux box?  I am just a little worried about the security in the older versions.

Comment: Is it Bedrock or Java Edition?

Comment: The difference in security for versions isn’t bad in non-historical versions (1.0+), they all use the same auth servers for the accounts. I myself and many other people use versions like 1.7 and 1.8 servers and they are not any less safe than modern ones. Also, an important part in your security issue, **would random people connect to this or would the IP only be given to his friends?**

Comment: If you're worried, for peace of mind, run the server in a sandbox / virtual machine like Docker or Snap.

Comment: Try asking this on https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=minecraft as it's not a question for Arqade.

Answer (score 4):

Minecraft server version has nothing to do with it's security, no version has any bugs that would allow for any sort of exploit to control the computer the server is on.  Having people know you're IP is a different story, however all this really opens you up to is DDoS and DoS attacks, and these will only happen if someone gets really upset.  If this is not a public server, and the IP will only go out to trusted individuals, there is almost no risk at all.  If it is public, it depends on the type of server. An anarchy server will be high-risk, but a SMP will be low risk.

Update: The Log4J exploit has created a vulnerability in all pre-1.18 server versions. See here for fixes: https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4416199399693-Security-Vulnerability-in-Minecraft-Java-Edition